# Javascript function call doesn't work from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to call a custom made function from a link but somehow it doesn't work. Alert doesn't pop up. Help appreciated! This is my code:

```
$.each(data.Tables, function(i, data){
    link = '<a href="#" onclick=test()>' + data.tableName + '</a>';
    tr.append("<td>" + link + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data.rowCount + "</td>");
    $("#tablesTable").append(tr);
});
```

This is my function:

```
function test (){
    alert("Doesn't work");
}
```

If I change the link row to this, alert comes after clicking the link.

```
link = '<a href="#" onclick=alert()>' + data.tableName + '</a>';
```

Comment: Did you place the function within document ready ?

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: Error in console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined". I placed the function within document ready.

Comment: It's also always good to wrap attribute values in quotes.

Comment: Is the test function defined inside another function?

Comment: Test function is right after document ready, not inside another function.

Comment: @JohnP: When you use inline event handlers, the functions need to be in global scope.  That's why it couldn't find `test()`.

Comment: @JohnP if you are defining `test` within the document ready handler, it is within another function and won't be visible outside that handlers scope.  You can either expose it: `window.test = test` or, better yet, use @RocketHazmat's suggested approach below.

Comment: Thank you adeneo and others! I removed my function away from document ready and now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has no place in HTML attributes.  jQuery can actually bind event handlers to elements even if they are not in the DOM, so I'd suggest you do something like this:

```
$.each(data.Tables, function(i, data){
    var $link = $('<a></a>', { // Create a new jQuery object
        href: '#',
        html: data.tableName
    }).click(function(){
        // Your code here...
        alert("Doesn't work");
    });

    // We can't use '+' since $link is no longer a string
    tr.append($link.wrap('<td></td>').parent());

    tr.append("<td>" + data.rowCount + "</td>");

    $("#tablesTable").append(tr);
});
```

This uses jQuery to create the `<a>` tag, then uses `.click()` to bind the event.

Comment: Delegation would likely be better here, no?

Comment: @JasonP: You mean to use `.on()` to bind the event outside of the `each` loop?  Yeah, probably, but this is good for a quick solution.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
link = '<a href="#" onclick=test()>' + data.tableName + '</a>';
```

to this

```
link = '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:test();">' + data.tableName + '</a>';
```

Comment: You don't put `javascript:` inside `onclick` attributes.  That's only for when you use the `href` (which you should never do).

Comment: That is pure valid code, no one can stop you from doing that.

Comment: "`onclick="test();"` is the more accepted way to do this", I guess is what I was trying to say.

Comment: who told you ? this is accepted way ? I have seen at countless places using javascript protocol.

Comment: They were probably using as the `href`, such as `href="javascript:test();"`.  In events, you just need the JavaScript code.  I can't find any docs saying you should or shouldn't have `javascript:` in your inline events.  All I was saying was that it's superfluous!